# How do I select the 1st row from a selection of 10 random rows

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a 1000 rows in my table.

I want to select 10 of those at random.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Then I want to select the row in that result with the highest value for number

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1
```

Can anyone help me come up with an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: How would the final result differ from simply `SELECT ... RAND() LIMIT 1`?

Comment: I want the results weighted by number. So the higher the number the more often it will show up. I also don't want it to show up everytime

Comment: I don't get it. If it's random, it's not being ranked by number. It won't show the same record every time, since it's random... Am I missing something?

Comment: if you shrink the data set to 11 and select 10 of those, then take the highest number, the majority of the time it will give you the same number. every once in a while it will return the 2nd highest number

Comment: I get your point now. I think this can be resolved with a simple subquery. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1
```